# JavaScript: Check value of input

Tags: javascript, input

Here is some information about my code:

HTML:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="red" id="name" name="name" onclick="checkName(this);" onkeyup="checkName(this);" onblur="checkName(this);" placeholder="Name*">
<button type="submit" onClick="validateName();">SUBMIT YER WORK!</button>
```

CSS:

```
input.red:focus {
    background: #E45F56 !important;
    border: 1px solid #E45F56 !important;
}
input.false {
    background: #E45F56 !important;
    border: 1px solid #E45F56 !important;
}
input.true {
    background: #4aaaa5 !important;
    border: 1px solid #4aaaa5 !important;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var status = 0;
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

function checkName(name) {
    if (!name) {
        status = 0;
        name.classList.remove("red");
        name.classList.remove("true");
        name.classList.add("false");
    } else if (name) {
        status = 1;
        name.classList.remove("red");
        name.classList.remove("false");
        name.classList.add("true");
    }
}

function validateName() {
    if (status == 0) {
        window.location = "#fail";
        name.focus();
    } else if (status == 1) {
        window.location = "#submitted";
    }
}
```

The whole idea is, that if you type in that input field you'll get a direct feedback, cause the field turns either red or green. If you click the button, a popup will open.

The only problem with this code is, that every time I click into the input field it turns green and not red. This means additionally, that if I click that button the "#submitted"-popup will pop up, even though I've nothing typed yet.

Comment: It's not what you asked, but I suggest you to change `onclick="checkName(this);"` for `onfocus="checkName(this);"`, because with onfocus the event will fire even if the user get in the textfield by pressing TAB.

Comment: Haven't thought about that - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is a reference to an object, so `!name` will always be false. You probably wanted

```
if (!name.value) {
```

or possibly

```
if (!name.value.trim()) {
```

...if you want to ignore leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use jquery. It's easier syntax.
You can use blur too:

```
var name = $("#name").val();
name.blur(checkname);
```

Then you use the function:

```
function checkname(name){

    if(name.length < 4){ //if you type less than 4 chars
        name.css('border-color','#red');
        return false;
    }
    else if(name == ""){ //if the input is empty
        name.css('border-color','#red');
        return false;   
    }else{
      name.css('border-color','#green');
      return true; //validate the fields
    }

}
```

I hope it helps!